# Place content from form directly on to an image

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a form where the content I enter is printed on to an image (saving me altering it in Photoshop every time I need to modify it).

I've set up the form with input fields and a form, and need to now find a script that just pastes my input onto the image.

See image below for reference and my form for info:

[image: form]

Comment: Removed tag from title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the whole thing completely client side, using canvas and a bit of JS.

1. First, get your canvas and context references:

   ```
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ```
2. Use `drawImage` to draw the template image into the canvas:

   ```
   var imgSource = new Image();
   imgSource.onload = function () {
       ctx.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0);
   };

   //idealy the source is data uri - otherwise from the same domain,
   //or you'll encounter security errors;
   imgSource.src = 'your template image';
   ```
3. Next, use `fillText` to add your text in the right place on the canvas:

   ```
   ctx.font = '40px Arial';
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fillText(text, 10, 200); //draw text at position x=10, y=200
   ```
4. Finally, use a bit of code to download the resulting image:

   ```
   var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   var anchor = document.createElement('a');
   anchor.download = 'save_me.png';
   anchor.href = url;
   anchor.click();
   ```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doLLvmca/2/) to this sample.

Comment: Hi Aleks, looks good this way does - i've only been able to position one element in the JS though - i need six in total. I've given each input a different id but struggling understanding the javascript.

Comment: @OwenDawson In the sample code on jsfiddle, there's function `addText` - change it to have three parameters - one for the text string, the other two for coordinates.  Then on lines 31 to 33 text is retrieved from the input field and added to the image using that function.  You'll need to replicate that code 6 times with 6 different input ids.

Comment: Hi @Aleks G, is this what the perameters should look like? I'm getting a little confused.


`function addText(plot, price) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.font = '40px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText(plot, 10, 200);

    ctx.font = '40px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText(price, 100, 200);
}`

Comment: & the function to add
`document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('plot');
    var text = input.value.trim();

    var input = document.getElementById('price');
    var text = input.value.trim();

    addText(plot,price);
    input.value = "";
};`

Comment: @OwenDawson First, you don't need to set `fillStyle` and `font` twice - once in the beginning it enough.  Second, when get values of textfields, you need to assign them to `plot` and `price` variables respectively, not variable `text` both times - otherwise your `addText` call would receive two undefined variables. Finally, only declare variable with `var` the first time in a function.

Comment: top man, i've got it working! Just got to start looking at algorithms to get a percentage of the input value.

Answer (score 0):

CSS method

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display form input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="input1">
        <input type="text" id="input2">
        <input type="text" id="input3">
        <input type="text" id="input4">
    </form>
    <img src="yourimage.jpg">
    <!--You should position these elements with css above your image-->
    <p id="text1"></p>
    <p id="text2"></p>
    <p id="text3"></p>
    <p id="text4"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
// Detect form changes
$('form').change(function(){
    // Get value of form
    $input1 = $('#input1').val();
    $input2 = $('#input2').val();
    $input3 = $('#input3').val();
    $input4 = $('#input4').val();

    // Change text of placeholders to form values
    $('#text1').text($input1);
    $('#text2').text($input2);
    $('#text3').text($input3);
    $('#text4').text($input4);
});
```

---

PHP method

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form to jpeg</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="toimage.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="text" name="text2">
        <input type="text" name="text3">
        <input type="text" name="text4">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

toimage.php:

```
<?php
// Set image type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Create image from photo
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('yourimage.jpg');

// Set color RGB
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

// Path to font
// Must be .TTF
$font_path = 'arial.TTF';

// Get input values and store in vars
$text1 = $_GET['text1'];
$text2 = $_GET['text2'];
$text3 = $_GET['text3'];
$text4 = $_GET['text4'];

// imagettftext($jpg_image, text-size, text angle, x-co, y-co, color, path to font .TTF, text);
// You will have to change the text-size, x-co and y-co so that each text item is positioned exactly at the place you want it to.
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 25, 50, $white, $font_path, $text1);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 25, 150, $white, $font_path, $text2);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 25, 250, $white, $font_path, $text3);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 25, 350, $white, $font_path, $text4);

// Display jpg
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
// Delete from memory
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply EndPostive - Ideally I want to be able to place the inputted text over the image and save the image as a jpeg so i can email.

I'm open to any easier suggestions just i thought this one was the only way

Comment: @OwenDawson no problem, using PHP is certainly possible. I do not know any other easier way to save it as jpeg. If no one else has answered in 6 hours I can look into it for you when I get back home. Shouldn't be too difficult :)

Comment: Ah cheers buddy, just thought of doing it this way as an end user can easily do it without using PS etc, there is some bits online but it doesn't really fit into what I need I dont think.

Comment: Hi, @OwenDawson I edited my reply. Let me know if it worked for you :)